# How do i code an afk command that comes out the way dyno runs

Tags: python, performance, request, discord.py, command

I need help making a afk command for my discord server. When the afk command is triggered, my bot doesn't respond with a reasoning when you ping the person whos afk. Also, when you return from being afk and type, the bot doesn't send a message saying "(user) is no longer afk". Please help me and tell me what i'm doing wrong and how can I fix this?

```
afkdict = {User: "their reason"} # somewhere in the code
@bot.command("afk")
async def afk(ctx, reason=None):
    afkdict[ctx.user] = reason
    await ctx.send("You are now afk. Beware of the real world!")
```

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
afkdict = {user: "their reason"}
# some other checks here

```
for user, reason in afkdict.items():
    if user in message.mentions:
        if reason is None:
            reason = ""
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{user} is AFK", color=0xFF0000, description=reason[:2500])
        await message.reply()
```

I was expecting this to work, the way dyno works. When i ran the command i got a message back saying user has no context. I dont know what to do anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a couple of issues. Firstly, you are redefining `afkdict` in your `on_message` function it doesn't matter that you're adding users to it in the `afk` command. Secondly, when you're doing `await message.reply()`, you're not actually sending the created embed along with it.

I've resolved those problems and changed the logic slightly. Instead of iterating over the users in the `afk_dict` and checking if they're mentioned, we're iterating over the mentions and seeing if they're in the `afk_dict`. I'm also using `user.id` rather user objects as keys.

```py
# defined somewhere
afk_dict = {}

@bot.command()
async def afk(ctx, reason=None):
    afk_dict[ctx.user.id] = reason
    await ctx.send("You are now afk. Beware of the real world!")


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    # do whatever else you're doing here
    
    for user in message.mentions:
        if user.id not in afk_dict:
            continue
        # mentioned used is "afk"
        reason = afk_dict[user.id] or ""
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{user.mention} is AFK", color=0xFF0000, description=reason[:2500])
        await message.reply(embed=embed)
```